# How to switch to listview on drawer navigation menu item click

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, navigation, navigation-drawer

I want to open a listview when click on item for this i used listfragment and for drawer navigation i customized default drawer navigation activity when I'm clicking on menu item of navigation drawer, the whole listfragment opens instead of fragment inside drawer navigation and because of this Im unable to get back to drawer navigation activity(for clicking other items) as listfragment opens as separate fragment, here is my code

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.teams) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Teams clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ListFragment listfrag
      =
(ListFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("listfragment");

        if(listfrag==null){
           listfrag =new listFragment();

FragmentTransaction transact=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transact.add(android.R.id.content,listfrag,"lstfragment");
            transact.commit();

        }
```

and code of listfragment

```
public class listFragment extends ListFragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup 
container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   ViewGroup rootview = 
(ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlistview, container, false);

    //data source
    String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };

 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new 
ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.listviewitem, R.id.tvteamsname, from);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    //  Retain the ListFragment instance across Activity re-creation
    setRetainInstance(true);

    return rootview;

}
```

Comment: simply open the listFragment in a frame or container inside your navigationDrawer activity, this is how your navigationDrawer menu is also visible to you while you in ListFragment

Comment: Could you exaggrate little more, where can i add fragment tag or what?

Comment: below i have answer the idea how you can implement this. Now you just have to add a frame to you activity and then you can replace any fragment to that frame and your navigation view is visible the preceding fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first add a frame to your `Activity` where you have added `navigationDrawerMenu`.

```
FragmentTransaction transact=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transact.add(android.R.id.content,listfrag,"lstfragment");
transact.commit();
```

replace this code with

```
FragmentTransaction transact=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transact.replace(R.id.your_frame, listfrag);
transact.addToBackStack(null); // or you can add some string
transact.commit();
```